# JavaScript Type Coercion preference

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I was trying to understand the core working of javascript. One of things that I stumbled upon is,when I do

```
1 + "2"
```

it returns "12".But it could possibly also be 3. I deduce that maybe it is because a number could always be converted to a string but not a string to a number.

Also I noticed that

```
100 + true = 101.
```

Here too that deduction works.the Boolean is converted to a number. But how does the data type conversion exactly work?

Comment: You can check this [link](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/) out. In both of your examples conversion was done correctly.

Comment: Note that this behavior *should* follow ECMAScript standards for types across browsers, but I wouldn't rely on it to always be the case. Be careful and be sane and make your values similar before adding them...ECMAScript defines a lengthy way of determining what gets evaluated how at http://es5.github.io/x9.html - it mainly talks about testing values (`1 == "1"`?) but the same conversion rules should apply when operating on those values.

Comment: You can read about the plus operator here, http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1, and follow the links to the function used.

Answer (score 2):

You should see this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals. It will easy to understand how javascript work.

In your first example  `1 + "2"` it return `12` because javascript concat integer and string if you want to sum two values. But if you want to do `sum 1+2 = 3` because two value are integer. If two values are string and integer then integer value automatically converted to string.

In your second example, `100 + true = 101.` 100 is integer and `true =1` then it sum `100+1 =101` because these two basically integer.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator in JavaScript has two uses. The first one is to add and the second one is to concatenate. JavaScript will only add if both are numbers. Anything else will be concatenated. This is actually a mistake in JavaScript which was never yet corrected. 
JavaScript will only convert a string to a number in a comparison.